# What is a good free "game development organisation" site?

Tags: teamwork

I'm searching for a site that will help me to design a game. I don't have a development team in the same location. They are all located somewhere over the world. I am searching for a kind of site that allows people to post ideas and suggestions, but moreover to have control over who has the control over what. For example, one makes the graphics and has several people "under" him that can get a certain task to make a certrain graphic. This has to be easily found on this site.

Does anyone know a good site like this? I prefer it to be free.

Comment: Kinda sound like you need an issue tracker / private forum?

Comment: Though there may be gamedev-specific answers, this question is really about general software project management.  I'm going to flag it for migration.   Who knows, maybe [this fledgling subdomain](http://pm.stackexchange.com/) might like it. (Don't re-post!)

Comment: This is a software recommendation type question that pretty much all SE sites don't allow anymore. Just search for project management software and try and find one that suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Project management is an ever evolving process that every team deals with. There are many development methodologies that can facilitate different team sizes, deadlines, project types, and just personal preferences. Software development today is being heavily developed by teams implementing various Agile development methodologies. Agile development focuses on short term deliverable tasks, customer feedback, and flexibility in planning. There are many different software solutions that can help a team operate using Agile. I would recommend doing some research on how Agile works. There are a number of web based Agile software packages, here are a few of them.

*Edit* After posting this, I realize a full agile implementation may be unrealistic, and I have thus attached links to other free, web based project management solutions.

http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2380448,00.asp

http://agilescout.com/best-agile-scrum-tools/

http://www.versionone.com/